# Programmatically clear Facebook SDK 4.0 session on Android

Tags: android, facebook, logout

I integrated Facebook login into my app, and It works fine. The issue is with the logout.

When I open the Facebook app on my device, I can perform a logout, so that the next time I open It, It will ask my If I want to login with my usual account, login with another account or even create a new account. Good, that is expected.

But this doesn't happen with my app. I mean, If the user opens my app, clicks in "logout" and the code below is ran

```
// Initialize Facebook SDK on the beginning.
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());
...
// Logout on user choice.
LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
```

the next time he is back on the app and clicks to login he will be logged in directly with his account, he won't be asked with each account he wants to login.

I image that I need to clear all informations (tokens?) that are saved, which are being used into this directly login. Is this correct? If yes, how can I do it?

Thank you,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am using this method. It's for SDK 4.6.0, but I guess it should be the same as 4.0. If not, just upgrade ;)

```
public void logoutFromFacebook(final LogoutFacebookListener listener) {

        if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() == null) {
            // already logged out
            listener.onLoggedOutFromFacebook();
            return;
        }

        new GraphRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), "/me/permissions/", null, HttpMethod.DELETE, new GraphRequest
                .Callback() {

            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphResponse graphResponse) {

                LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
                listener.onLoggedOutFromFacebook();
            }
        }).executeAsync();
    }
```

Listener:

```
public interface LogoutFromFacebookListener {

    void onLoggedOutFromFacebook();
}
```

Comment: Improved a little bit...now the app is requesting for the user to confirm the Facebook permission again, but still with the same user.

Comment: @DaniloSetton Ok :) If this is done, please accept my answer to close this question.

Comment: Actually I can't yet login with different users...It still redirection me to a 'direct login', the only difference is that I need to grant the permissions again...

Comment: @DaniloSetton That's strange. Have you tried to update the sdk version to 4.6.0 ?

Comment: @DaniloSetton By the way, I forgot to mention, that this code worked only within the website Facebook. There is no way how you could log out a user in the Facebook application, you have no authority there.

Answer (score 2):

It seams like when you trying to login, facebook sdk uses your web browser (chrome, etc) in your case. And when you call `LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();` you do logout just from facebook sdk, but you are still staying loggedin in your web browser. [The Android and iOS SDKs don't currently support re-authentication.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/reauthentication) Hope they will be in future ;)

Comment: This put me on the right path. I called the `logout` SDK method _and_ went to the iOS Settings > Safari > Clear History and Website Data. This allowed me to login with a different user. Thanks for this info!